Is there any way to compile C++ code by g++ without any disk-writing?
I have a special Linux environment: all files and folders are read-only and G++ is installed. I am also unable to run sudo. I can just run a C++ program on it. I want to compile another piece of C++ code, and I wrote some code like this:
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cassert>

#include<unistd.h>
#include<wait.h>
#include<sys/mman.h>

constexpr char GPPPATH[]="/bin/g++";

int compile(std::string const& program){
    int exefid=memfd_create("exe",0);
    int subpid=fork();
    assert(subpid!=-1);
    if (subpid==0){
        int pid=getpid();
        int programfid=memfd_create("program",0);
        write(programfid,program.c_str(),program.size());
        std::string const programPath="/proc/"+std::to_string(pid)+"/fd/"+std::to_string(programfid);
        std::string const ExePath="/proc/"+std::to_string(pid)+"/fd/"+std::to_string(exefid);
        dup2(fileno(stdout),fileno(stderr));
        execl(GPPPATH,GPPPATH,"-xc++",programPath.c_str(),"-o",ExePath.c_str(),NULL);
        throw;
    }else{
        int status;
        waitpid(subpid,&status,0);
        if (!WIFEXITED(status)) throw;
    }
    return exefid;
}
int main(int argc,char** argv,char** envp){
    int fid=compile("""#include<bits/stdc++.h>\nint main(){std::cout<<\"IAKIOI\";}""");
    fexecve(fid,argv,envp);
}

To save the output file, I used memfd_create.
Of course, it didn't work. G++ was trying to create temporary files on the disk but failed. Is there any way to make g++ compile C+ without any disk-writing?
I also tried to use -pipe but I found it still created temp files:
╭─     /tmp                                                         21:12:45
╰─❯ cat tmp.cpp                                  
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
int main(){std::cout<<114514;}

╭─     /tmp                                                         21:12:48
╰─❯ strace g++ -pipe tmp.cpp -o tmp 2>&1 | grep "/tmp"
getcwd("/tmp", 1024)                    = 5
readlink("/tmp/tmp.cpp", 0x7ffc1ec38d50, 1023) = -1 EINVAL (无效的参数)
getcwd("/tmp", 1024)                    = 5
readlink("/tmp/tmp", 0x7ffc1ec38d50, 1023) = -1 EINVAL (无效的参数)
access("/tmp", R_OK|W_OK|X_OK)          = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|S_ISVTX|0777, st_size=20504576, ...}, 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/ccolfqPz.o", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/cckzgSEX.res", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 3
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/cckzgSEX.res", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=0, ...}, 0) = 0
unlink("/tmp/cckzgSEX.res")             = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/ccolfqPz.o", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=2064, ...}, 0) = 0
unlink("/tmp/ccolfqPz.o")               = 0

My mounts are, according to /proc/mounts
/dev/vda1 /etc/passwd ext4 ro,nosuid,relatime,errors=remount-ro 0 0
/dev/vda1 /etc/terminfo ext4 ro,nosuid,relatime,errors=remount-ro 0 0
/dev/vda1 /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive ext4 ro,nosuid,relatime,errors=remount-ro 0 0
proc /proc proc ro,nosuid,relatime 0 0
udev /dev devtmpfs ro,nosuid,relatime,size=11892204k,nr_inodes=2973051,mode=755 0 0
/dev/vda1 /nix ext4 ro,nosuid,relatime,errors=remount-ro 0 0
/dev/vda1 /tmp/exec_ir9g3uq9 ext4 ro,nosuid,relatime,errors=remount-ro 0 0
none /proc proc rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,hidepid=invisible 0 0
none /proc/sys tmpfs ro,nosuid,relatime,size=0k 0 0


Have you tried g++ -pipe?

@Devon Yes, g++ still create temp file.

do you mean without any disk writes or without any filesystem writes, including any in-memory filesystems?

@ilkkachu maybe it's ok. But now I can't find any folder that I have permission to write.

What are your mounted filesystems (either by running mount or cat /proc/mounts)?

content in https://www.luogu.com.cn/paste/3qde80l4 @ErikF

That's very interesting! /proc/sys looks really suspicious! Even in a container, that would usually be proc /proc/sys proc ro,… (if at all present) but not none /proc/sys tmpfs ro,….

scratch that! What's up with all the nonsensical /dev/vda1 mounts? Ext4 doesn't have subvolumes, so these mounts are plain impossible. Whatever you're running in, your operating system is lying to you about the mounts, as far as we can tell. In other words, this whole system doesn't behave in any way like a proper Linux system, and we hence can't infer anything, because it might allow or prohibit anything.

sure; just set the TMPDIR environment variable before you call gcc (or g++ or any other GCC compiler). Set it to a path that's on a tmpfs mount. Chances are your /tmp or /run, or /run/user/$(id -u)/ are already such a tmpfs mount! (check the output of mount for such, e.g. mount | grep tmpfs)
If need to create such a mount,
sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=10M tmpfs /path/to/empty/directory


Sorry. I forget to say that I cannot use sudo.

you don't necessarily have to; as said, chances are you do have a tmpfs mount somewhere.

Looks like the OP's /tmp is not a ramdisk since the strace output in the question uses it and presumably failed. /run might work though. @MrPython, check the output of mount | grep tmpfs. Do you have anything there?

@terdon No mount and /run on the system

@MrPython contents of /proc/mounts ?

content in https://www.luogu.com.cn/paste/3qde80l4 @Marcus Müller

@MrPython I had to click on a button I couldn't understand, but thanks! I'm adding that info to your question.
